# Function template with an operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

In C++, can you have a templated operator on a class? Like so:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    template<class T>
    T operator()() { /* return some T */ };
}
```

This actually seems to compile just fine, but the confusion comes in how one would use it:

```
MyClass c;
int i = c<int>(); // This doesn't work
int i = (int)c(); // Neither does this*
```

The fact that it compiles at all suggests to me that it's doable, I'm just at a loss for how to use it! Any suggestions, or is this method of use a non-starter?

Comment: What does it mean "this doesn't work/neither does this"? What happens?

Comment: Compiler barfs on you, that's what happens :)

Comment: I swear I've seen this question on SO before...I cannot find it though, so obviously one cannot blame you.

Comment: Ah, found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942170/c-functor-and-function-templates

Comment: Thanks. Guess I was just hitting the wrong keywords when I tried searching. (Didn't think to try functor. That should have been obvious in retrospect)

Comment: That's ok. In honesty, I used a Google search with `site:stackoverflow.com` before it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to specify `T`.

```
int i = c.operator()<int>();
```

Unfortunately, you can't use the function call syntax directly in this case.

Edit: Oh, and you're missing `public:` at the beginning of the class definition.

Comment: Nice. Kudos on the quick and accurate answer! Unfortunately that's probably to verbose for my uses (since my code is intended to be called by others I want to avoid confusion) so I'll just have to find another route. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you're probably better off defining a `get` method instead of `operator()`. Then you could write `c.get<int>()`.

Comment: Actually, there is an idiom flying around that's used by many: free get function (tuples use `get<N>(some_tuple)`, boost.variant uses `get<T>(some_variant)`). So yours would look like `get<T>(c)`, with `get` being defined in `MyClass`'es namespace).

Comment: In this case I needed both a call that returned a value and one that didn't. I implemented *Evaluate<type>()* for the returning version, and *Execute()* for the non-returning, and then allowed the user to call the () operator as an alternative to Evaluate. (The names make sense in context, since they are executing functions defined in a script.) So essentially, yes, I implemented a get function :) 

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 21):

You're basically right. It is legal to define templated operators, but they can't be called directly with explicit template arguments.

If you have this operator:

```
template <typename T>
T operator()();
```

as in your example, it can only be called like this:

```
int i = c.operator()<int>();
```

Of course, if the template argument could be deduced from the arguments, you could still call it the normal way:

```
template <typename T>
T operator()(T value);

c(42); // would call operator()<int>
```

An alternative could be to make the argument a reference, and store the output there, instead of returning it:

```
template <typename T>
void operator()(T& value);
```

So instead of this:

```
int r = c.operator()<int>();
```

you could do

```
int r;
c(r);
```

Or perhaps you should just define a simple `get<T>()` function instead of using the operator.

Answer (score 4):

Aren't you thinking of

```
class Foo {
    public:
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const { return T(42); }
};

Foo foo;

int i = (int) foo; // less evil: static_cast<int>(foo);
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/oPgtnf). This proves you do not need to specify the template argument, despite the claim in the accepted answer.

Comment: Works in this case, but I was thinking of `c<int>++`. I mean this shouldn't work, and I am kinda abusing notation there...

Comment: @kim366: Since that has no meaning, it's rather pointless to think about it. It shouldn't work, and it doesn't work.