# Cpp templates functor that need get void or int

Tags: c++

How can I create a functor (in templates) that get void or int

```
template <class T>
Int TEMP::operator()(T s)
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Overload.......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ functor and function templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942170/c-functor-and-function-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Probably by not using templates:

```
template<class T> int TEMP<T>::operator()(int s)
{
    ...
}

template<class T> int TEMP<T>::operator()()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what TEMP is so I can't help.

Comment: Temp load dll and get the function. After that it call to the function and need (if not void) to transfer params

Comment: What I meant is that you didn't show the structure of TEMP, we don't even know if it is a template class or structure.

Comment: Template class. Get dll path and function name. Loading the dll and after the function. After that you can use functor to use the dll function normally.

Comment: I edited my answer, but as long as you don't give the prototype of your class TEMP (which seems to be a huge secret), I can't be sure it works.

Comment: And why do you want the operator to be templated since you just want int and void?

Comment: I load the dll dynamic, so I need create pointer to function with metadata about which parameters need to pass. (Typedef int (__cdecl * f_func)()